# Automatically disconnecting a F connector

Tags: testing

I have no electrical engineering experience.

I need to test a module, this module has what I believe to be a F-type RF connector to a device. I need to be able to disconnect that RF connector automatically.

Is there any kind of product or device that can be used to programmatically dis/re-connect a cable like this - some kind of terminal?

If not, how does automated hardware testing cope with requirements to physically disconnect devices?

Comment: A "chip" with an F connector? Seems more than a little unlikely... Do you actually have a circuit board or module of some sort with an F connector?

Comment: I believe that the correct term for it is module yes.

Comment: I have seen push-on "quick connect" F connectors -- instead of a threaded nut, they just have some springy "fingers" that make the shield connection. Often seen on the RF modulators for old-time TV game systems.

Comment: Have you considered an RF relay?

Comment: If the connector has to be *actually disconnected* they do it with motors or solenoids, and mechanical linkages.

Comment: All that's required is that data from the GPS antenna does not reach the module.

Comment: Hearth, how would I go about disabling a RF relay automatically?